# I can't open the Software Center on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, software-center, crash

When I try to open the Software Center it’s just white and crashes after 5 seconds. I tried to uninstall and then install it again through the Terminal, but it did not work.

Output of `software-center` in the Terminal:

```
SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-sv, E:Paketlistan eller statusfilen kunde inte tolkas eller öppnas.
2015-11-03 20:23:40,237 - softwarecenter.db.enquire - ERROR - _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 115, in _get_estimate_nr_apps_and_nr_pkgs
    tmp_matches = enquire.get_mset(0, len(self.db), None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 183, in <module>
    app.run(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1378, in run
    self.show_available_packages(args)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/app.py", line 1316, in show_available_packages
    self.view_manager.set_active_view(ViewPages.AVAILABLE)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/session/viewmanager.py", line 150, in set_active_view
    view_widget.init_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/panes/availablepane.py", line 227, in init_view
    self.cache, self.db, self.icons, self.apps_filter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 80, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 326, in build
    self._build_homepage_view()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 121, in _build_homepage_view
    self._append_whats_new()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 255, in _append_whats_new
    whats_new_cat = self._update_whats_new_content()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/ui/gtk3/views/lobbyview.py", line 240, in _update_whats_new_content
    docs = whats_new_cat.get_documents(self.db)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/categories.py", line 131, in get_documents
    nonblocking_load=False)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 330, in set_query
    self._blocking_perform_search()
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/enquire.py", line 225, in _blocking_perform_search
    matches = enquire.get_mset(0, self.limit, None, xfilter)
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/appfilter.py", line 89, in __call__
    if (not pkgname in self.cache and
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/db/pkginfo_impl/aptcache.py", line 281, in __contains__
    return self._cache.__contains__(k)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__contains__'
erik@erik-P35-DS3P:~$ Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/software-center/update-software-center-agent", line 81, in <module>
    cache = apt.Cache(memonly=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 107, in __init__
    self.open(progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apt/cache.py", line 151, in open
    self._cache = apt_pkg.Cache(progress)
SystemError: E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-sv, E:Paketlistan eller statusfilen kunde inte tolkas eller öppnas.
```

---

Output of `LANG=C software-center`:

```
2015-11-03 20:33:55,461 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.app - INFO - setting up proxy 'None'
2015-11-03 20:33:57,683 - softwarecenter.region - WARNING - failed to use geoclue: 'org.freedesktop.Geoclue.Error.notAvailable: Geoclue master client has no usable Address providers'
2015-11-03 20:33:58,598 - softwarecenter.backend.reviews - WARNING - Could not get usefulness from server, no username in config file
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `software-center` when you execute that from within a terminal? It will probably print out an error message there that can help to debug the problem.

Comment: Start the command again: `LANG=C software-center` and [edit] your question to add the output.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following two commands should solve your problem:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get update
```

The first command will delete all your downloaded package index files while the second one will re-download them all.

Probably a faulty package list is causing your problem.

---

**Note:** This will take a while to download, depending on your connection speed. If you want, you could try a minimal intervention first by only deleting the file mentioned in the error message:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/repository.spotify.com_dists_stable_non-free_i18n_Translation-sv
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Instead of being so specific, it is OK to rm -rf /var/lib/lists/* as @Byte says first.  I wouldn't trust the second one.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Open the terminal from Applications>Accessories>Terminal

then type

```
gksudo software-center
```

If it does the same thing, you will at least have a text output of the error. Post it back here.

**2)** Here is another way to solve it:

Please remove the lines where cairo and gusty written.
To do this 
type

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

(line 60 the one with gusty in it) and save the file as before.

Gusty is old, very old, and is no longer supported.

Kind regards

Comment: Copied from various posts in https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1450914.  Please read http://askubuntu.com/help/referencing.